# Geth name instead of address

Tags: console, ethereum

I've seen lots of pools send out transactions and it shows their pool name instead of just a long wallet address.  I'm sure it's a simple geth console command but I can't seem to figure out which one it is.  Probably namereg or something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to names on ethereum block explorers, like https://etherscan.io?

If so, it is not a command in geth. The name is configured by the owners of those block explorers. So your only option would be to send them an email and ask for your address to have a "pretty name"

I hope this helps!